# Qt including resource directory structure inside executable

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I'm using QWebView to run a web app. There are 650+ files. Placing the web app's directory in the source directory does not result in the executable bundling the directory.

How do I include the entire web app directory so that the executable will be able to render the files.

Note: I have currently added index.html as a resource, and can access it with qrc:// - But since I cannot add the entire directory structure to a qrc (can I?), the executable does not include the other files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an XML node into the `.qrc` file **for each file** you want to use using the Qt resource system.

This can be done using a simple pre-build script. Take a look at [`qrcgen`](http://pyinsci.blogspot.de/2011/09/generating-qt-resource-files-from-whole.html). Quoting the blog post behind this link:

> The script I created, [qrcgen](https://github.com/fccoelho/qrcgen), takes a directory and a prefix, recursively scans the directory and generates a **.qrc** file with the same name as the directory scanned. It has solved my problem, and I hope it can help others. It is also available via PyPI, just "**easy_install qrcgen**".

---

In order to update the `.qrc` file whenever your directory contens change, you need to include this step into your build process:

- For **C++/Qt** projects, you can add this step in the build configuration in QtCreator or add in your qmake file a `system(...)` statement. Note that such commands aren't portable in general. (If it's not portable, you can put some operating system conditions around multiple commands.)
- For **PyQt/PySide** projects, I don't know how to do this, but I'm sure you find a solution for this too.